# libcurl response header missing Content-Length field

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

When I run `curl --header <url here>` from the command line, I am able to see quite a bit of information, including the desired field Content-Length.

But when I write a C script based on libcurl, including the line
`curl_easy_getinfo(c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T, &ContentLength);`

ContentLength ends up with a value of -1 and the header I receive is merely "HTTP/2 200".

I seem to be able to get the Content-Length field from the command line curl but not using C's libcurl. What gives?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int hcb(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data) {
    // this prints "HTTP/2 200"
    printf("%.*s\n", (int)(size*nmemb), ((char *) contents));
    return 0;
}

int wcb(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data) {
    printf("not implemented\n");
    return 0;
}

ssize_t myfunc(){
    char url[] = "http://thisisafakeurl.com/test.txt";
    CURL *c = curl_easy_init();
    if(c) {
        CURLcode res;
        curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, hcb);
        curl_easy_setopt(c, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wcb);
        res = curl_easy_perform(c);
        int ContentLength;
        curl_easy_getinfo(c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T, &ContentLength);
        // this line prints 23.
        printf("content length: %i\n", ContentLength);
        curl_easy_cleanup(c);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. I am not that familiar with libcurl, but it may be possible that you are not calling the libcurl functions properly, so it may be helpful if you showed exactly how you are calling them.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `curl_easy_getinfo`? Did it return `CURLE_OK`?

Comment: Are you calling `curl_easy_getinfo` before or after calling `curl_easy_perform`?

Comment: I added more details as requested. curl_easy_getinfo gives a value of 0. And I am calling curl_easy_getinfo after calling curl_easy_perform

Comment: And what was the return value of `curl_easy_perform`? You are storing it in the variable `res`, but you are not checking it.

Comment: The value was 23, which means that "an error was returned to libcurl from a write callback." And I added more details from my code to include my writefunction.

Comment: ["Your callback should return the number of bytes actually taken care of. If that amount differs from the amount passed to your callback function, it will signal an error condition to the library. This will cause the transfer to get aborted and the libcurl function used will return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR."](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html).  You should probably return "size * nmemb" to avoid this. (not tested)

Comment: The previous comment about the return value of the callback function applies to both `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, so both functions should be changed to indicate success (even if they do nothing).

Comment: I just made the change suggested by Christian. I'm still seeing curl_easy_perform return the value of 23. Edit: making change for headerfunction

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you change `return 0;` to `return nmemb;` in BOTH functions?

Comment: Brilliant. I changed the return value to size*nmemb in both the headerfunction and writefunction and now I am getting a meaningful header and ContentLength is showing the value that I was expecting. Thank you both for your assistance with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html) states the following:

> This callback function must return the number of bytes actually taken care of. If that amount differs from the amount passed in to your function, it will signal an error to the library. This will cause the transfer to get aborted and the libcurl function in progress will return `CURLE_WRITE_ERROR`.

The documentation for [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) states something very similar:

> Your callback should return the number of bytes actually taken care of. If that amount differs from the amount passed to your callback function, it will signal an error condition to the library. This will cause the transfer to get aborted and the libcurl function used will return `CURLE_WRITE_ERROR`.

Since your callback functions are always returning a value that indicates an error, according to the quoted documentation, this will cause the transfer to be aborted. That is probably why the line

```
curl_easy_getinfo(c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T, &ContentLength);
```

is failing.

In order to fix this, you should change your callback functions to always indicate success, by changing the line

```
return 0;
```

to

```
return nmemb;
```

in both functions.